# Python Handle Fortify Path Manipulation

Tags: python, fortify, path-manipulation

I am trying to run fortify analyzer on my python code and I am trying to read a file
created by my kubernetes server but I am being flagged as Path Manipulation..

What can I do to handle this Critical level in my python code?

```
namespace = open("/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace").read()
```

There is nothing I can do as this is the default path installation of my kubernetes server.

Comment: I am also running into the same issue with Python code. Any solution which worked for you.

Comment: Search for "path traversal attack" to get an idea about the vulnerability and some ways to overcome it